# Partial Class is created in new project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, partial-classes

Whenever i open any new project in Visual Studio, a partial class is created. I need only a simple class as i need to practice OOPS concepts.

How to create a new class or modify an existing partial class?

I might sound stupid! :-)

thanks!

Comment: which kind of project u selecting ?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, if you're just learning OOP you can ignore the fact that the class is partial. The other 'half' of the class is automatically generated code you don't need to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net generates a portion of your code, allowing you to extend it via the "partial" keyword.  This means that your code will get compiled into the same class as the code generated from XAML.

As far as trying to learn OOP goes, start with a command-line project and work your way up from there.  It might be easier to get going, and you'll feel like you have 100% of control over your creation.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following:

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson07.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why did you ask this question without telling us how you created the class?

I create classes all the time in Visual Studio, and the only time I get a partial class is when I choose a Page or related object type. I suspect you are not select class as the object type.